# How do I achieve Enum myEnum=Enum.FirstValue in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, syntax, enums

In C# I can use enums like this:

```
enum TrafficLight{Red,Yellow,Green};
.......
TrafficLight light=TrafficLight.Yellow;
```

In Objective-C I write:

```
    typedef enum trafficLight{
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Green
}TrafficLight;
```

But if I want to assign a variable of TrafficLight to TrafficLight.Yellow, it's not possible. I can only write

```
TrafficLight light=Yellow;
```

Is it possible to access the constants inside the enum with dot notation in Objective-C too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common practice is as follows

```
enum {
    TrafficLightColorRed,
    TrafficLightColorYellow,
    TrafficLightColorGreen
};
typedef NSInteger TrafficLightColor;


TrafficLightColor color = TrafficLightColorYellow;
```

this way the Type of the parameter is the Beginning of its enum elements

Sorry i could not get the result you were looking for but this is the stardard practice as far as I have seen.

Comment: Come on body, what can you do if this is what Objective-C offers?

Comment: well. you could code it in C instead. or C++ by changing the extension to .mm aside from that, you are in the world of objective c. Not the world of C#; I feel your pain. I am a C# developer in Objective C as well. I learned early on that whatever language you are working on you should conform to that codes standards instead of trying to transport the standards you use elsewhere into it.